# Disable Page Scroll On Open Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, scroll

I really hope you can help me with a problem I have. This is my first time asking anything so excuse me if I miss something but the problem is as follow:

I created a dropdown menu in Wordpress with Elementor Pro with the following code, and I just cant seem to find a solution on how to prevent page scroll when the dropdown is active on mobile devices.

```
<script>
//Toggle mobile menu & change icon on click

 jQuery(function() {
 jQuery('.nav-icon').click(function(){
      jQuery('#nav-container').slideToggle(280);
           jQuery('.nav-icon i').toggleClass('change-icon');

  });   
        
// Close mobile menu on screen size

jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
   let win = jQuery(this);
    if(win.width() > 1024){
      jQuery('#nav-container').show();
   } else {
     jQuery('#nav-container').hide();
   }
    
 });
});
</script>
```

I literally tried everything possible I found on the internet but with no luck. I am 99% sure I am making a mistake somewhere because coding is not my strength (not at all), so please any help will be highly appreciated!

Can someone help with the integration of the following code in my original one -

```
 function preventBehavior(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
};

    document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, {passive: false});
```

How to enable it only on icon click and disable it on click as well?

Comment: Usually overflow is set on body element. One of easy fixes is to append some class that will do "overflow:hidden" on top scrollable element (usually its body element) when dropdown is opened and vice versa.

Comment: I cant seem to make it work. I tried every possible option with the "overflow:hidden", and still page is scrollable and menu shrinks back

Comment: You can cancel `touchmove` event for mobile devices